# Why getSelectedItem().getDisplayString() returns <Strong>a</Strong>bc where it should return only abc for suggestion box in gwt

Tags: javascript, java, css, gwt, suggestbox

I am working with Suggestion box in gwt, I have applied a selectionHandler on that suggestion box. If I select "abc" value then getSelectedItem().getDisplaySring() should return "abc" instead it returns
    `<strong>`a`</strong>`bc.

Can someone help in this situation.. Why it returns wrong result.?

```
view.getMySuggetsionBox().addSelectionHandler(new SelectionHandler<SuggestOracle.Suggestion>() {

        @Override
        public void onSelection(SelectionEvent<Suggestion> event) {
            Window.alert(event.getSelectedItem().getDisplayString());

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're just actually looking for `getReplacementString` rather than `getDisplayString`.

Keep in mind that a suggest box is a text box with suggestions, not a select box / combo box with typeahead.